# netlify dev starts an endless loop

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, gatsby, netlify

I'm working on adding environment variables to make conditional switching for Netlify functions. When I run `CONTEXT=development netlify dev` I'm getting stuck in an endless loop and Lambda server keeps switching ports.

[Link on AWS functions](https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-dev-blog-starter/tree/master/.netlify/functions) and [`package.json`](https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-dev-blog-starter/blob/master/package.json).

```sh
yarn develop
yarn run v1.12.3
$ CONTEXT=development netlify dev
◈ Netlify Dev ◈
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_DEV_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_DEV_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_DEV_HOST_URL
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_FUNCTION_PASSWORD
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_HOST_URL
◈ Injected build setting env var:  GATSBY_DEV_FUNCTION_PASSWORD
◈ Starting Netlify Dev with gatsby
Waiting for localhost:8000.
◈ Lambda server is listening on 34567
$ npm run develop
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/s7/vtbv89nd3f99nlx5y9h94qk00000gn/T/yarn--1560352104668-0.36838903564793/node but npm is using /Users/skok/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> gatsby-dev-blog-starter@0.1.0 develop /Users/skok/dev/gatsby-dev-blog-starter
> CONTEXT=development netlify dev

.◈ Netlify Dev ◈
.◈ Starting Netlify Dev with gatsby
Waiting for localhost:8000.
◈ Lambda server is listening on 55396
$ npm run develop
.npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/s7/vtbv89nd3f99nlx5y9h94qk00000gn/T/yarn--1560352107238-0.9451571250276476/node but npm is using /Users/skok/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> gatsby-dev-blog-starter@0.1.0 develop /Users/skok/dev/gatsby-dev-blog-starter
> CONTEXT=development netlify dev

..◈ Netlify Dev ◈
.◈ Starting Netlify Dev with gatsby
.Waiting for localhost:8000.
◈ Lambda server is listening on 55412
$ npm run develop
.npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/s7/vtbv89nd3f99nlx5y9h94qk00000gn/T/yarn--1560352109773-0.46483751576396815/node but npm is using /Users/skok/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> gatsby-dev-blog-starter@0.1.0 develop /Users/skok/dev/gatsby-dev-blog-starter
> CONTEXT=development netlify dev

...◈ Netlify Dev ◈
.. ◈ Starting Netlify Dev with gatsby
.Waiting for localhost:8000.
◈ Lambda server is listening on 55436
$ npm run develop
..npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/s7/vtbv89nd3f99nlx5y9h94qk00000gn/T/yarn--1560352112263-0.5329314860894214/node but npm is using /Users/skok/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> gatsby-dev-blog-starter@0.1.0 develop /Users/skok/dev/gatsby-dev-blog-starter
> CONTEXT=development netlify dev
```

Netlify build log

```
8:01:43 AM: Build ready to start
8:01:52 AM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
8:01:52 AM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
8:01:52 AM: buildbot version: 75cd99f62ada9e21edea53208e8baf0eab85a045
8:01:52 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
8:01:52 AM: Starting to download cache of 255.0KB
8:01:52 AM: Finished downloading cache in 119.733265ms
8:01:52 AM: Starting to extract cache
8:01:52 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
8:01:52 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
8:01:53 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
8:01:53 AM: git clone https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-dev-blog-starter
8:01:56 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
8:01:56 AM: Found netlify.toml. Overriding site configuration
8:01:56 AM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the toml file: 'public' versus 'public/' in the site
8:01:56 AM: Different build command detected, going to use the one specified in the toml file: 'yarn build' versus 'CONTEXT=production gatsby build' in the site
8:01:56 AM: Different functions path detected, going to use the one specified in the toml file: '.netlify/functions' versus '' in the site
8:01:56 AM: Different base path detected, going to use the one specified in the toml file: '/' versus '' in the site
8:01:56 AM: Creating functions prep folder
8:01:56 AM: Starting build script
8:01:56 AM: Installing dependencies
8:01:58 AM: Downloading and installing node v11.5.0...
8:01:58 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v11.5.0/node-v11.5.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
8:01:59 AM:   0.1%
8:01:59 AM: 
##
8:01:59 AM:   2.9%
8:01:59 AM: 
###                                                                        4.7%
8:01:59 AM: 
####
8:01:59 AM:   5.9%
8:01:59 AM: 
#####                                                                      7.3%
8:01:59 AM: #####
8:01:59 AM:                         8.2%
8:01:59 AM: 
######
8:01:59 AM:   9.0%
8:01:59 AM: 
#######
8:01:59 AM:                           10.1%
8:01:59 AM: 
########
8:01:59 AM:  11.7%
8:01:59 AM: 
#########
8:01:59 AM:                13.0%
8:02:00 AM: 
###########
8:02:00 AM:                 15.5%
8:02:00 AM: 
############                                                              1
8:02:00 AM: 7.0%
8:02:00 AM: 
############
8:02:00 AM:         17.9%
8:02:00 AM: 
#############
8:02:00 AM:                                   18.4%
8:02:00 AM: 
##############                                                            20.2%
8:02:00 AM: 
###############                                                           21.0%
8:02:01 AM: 
###############
8:02:01 AM:  21.8%
8:02:01 AM: 
################
8:02:01 AM:  22.7%
8:02:01 AM: 
################
8:02:01 AM:  23.6%
8:02:01 AM: 
#################
8:02:01 AM:  24.4%
8:02:02 AM: 
#################
8:02:02 AM:                   24.9%
8:02:02 AM: 
##################
8:02:02 AM:  26.3%
8:02:02 AM: 
###################
8:02:02 AM:  26.9%
8:02:02 AM: 
######################
8:02:02 AM:      30.7%
8:02:03 AM: 
######################
8:02:03 AM:      31.0%
8:02:03 AM: 
#######################
8:02:03 AM:  32.8%
8:02:03 AM: 
#######################
8:02:03 AM:                             33.3%
8:02:03 AM: 
########################
8:02:03 AM:                 34.1%
8:02:04 AM: 
#########################
8:02:04 AM:  35.2%
8:02:04 AM: 
###########################                                               38.5%
8:02:04 AM: 
###########################
8:02:04 AM:     38.7%
8:02:04 AM: 
############################
8:02:04 AM:                                 39.7%
8:02:04 AM: 
#############################
8:02:04 AM:          41.0%
8:02:04 AM: 
##############################
8:02:04 AM:                                   41.8%
8:02:04 AM: 
###############################
8:02:04 AM:                               43.2%
8:02:04 AM: 
################################
8:02:04 AM:                      44.7%
8:02:05 AM: 
################################
8:02:05 AM:  45.6%
8:02:05 AM: 
#################################
8:02:05 AM:           46.4%
8:02:05 AM: 
##################################
8:02:05 AM:                  47.5%
8:02:05 AM: 
##################################
8:02:05 AM:                       48.5%
8:02:05 AM: 
###################################
8:02:05 AM:                               49.4%
8:02:05 AM: 
####################################
8:02:05 AM:  50.4%
8:02:05 AM: 
#####################################                                     51.8%
8:02:05 AM: 
######################################
8:02:05 AM:  53.1%
8:02:05 AM: 
#######################################
8:02:05 AM:  54.4%
8:02:06 AM: 
#######################################
8:02:06 AM:                                54.8%
8:02:06 AM: 
########################################
8:02:06 AM:                  56.3%
8:02:06 AM: 
#########################################
8:02:06 AM:  57.0%
8:02:06 AM: 
#########################################
8:02:06 AM:  57.7%
8:02:06 AM: 
#########################################
8:02:06 AM:                58.0%
8:02:06 AM: 
#########################################                                 5
8:02:06 AM: 8.2%
8:02:06 AM: 
##########################################
8:02:06 AM:  58.6%
8:02:07 AM: 
##########################################
8:02:07 AM:  59.4%
8:02:08 AM: 
##########################################
8:02:08 AM:          59.5%
8:02:08 AM: 
##########################################
8:02:08 AM:      59.5%
8:02:08 AM: 
##############################################
8:02:08 AM:      64.0%
8:02:08 AM: 
###################################################
8:02:08 AM:    71.0%
8:02:08 AM: 
###################################################
8:02:08 AM:                72.0%
8:02:09 AM: 
####################################################
8:02:09 AM:       73.0%
8:02:09 AM: 
#####################################################                     73.7%
8:02:09 AM: 
#####################################################
8:02:09 AM:  74.2%
8:02:09 AM: 
######################################################
8:02:09 AM:  75.0%
8:02:09 AM: 
######################################################
8:02:09 AM:              75.7%
8:02:09 AM: 
#####################################
8:02:09 AM: #################                    76.2%
8:02:10 AM: 
#######################################################
8:02:10 AM:  77.6%
8:02:10 AM: 
#######################################################
8:02:10 AM:  77.7%
8:02:10 AM: 
#################################################
8:02:10 AM: #######                  78.1%
8:02:10 AM: 
########################################################                  78.8%
8:02:11 AM: #
8:02:11 AM: ##############################################
8:02:11 AM: ###########                81.9%
8:02:11 AM: 
###########################################################               82.4
8:02:11 AM: %
8:02:11 AM: 
###########################################################
8:02:11 AM:  82.8%
8:02:11 AM: 
############################################################
8:02:11 AM:  84.7%
8:02:11 AM: 
#############################################################             85.7%
8:02:12 AM: 
##############################################################            86.5%
8:02:12 AM: 
#####################################################
8:02:12 AM: #########            86.6%
8:02:12 AM: 
#############################
8:02:12 AM: ##################################           87.5%
8:02:12 AM: 
###############################################################           88.1%
8:02:13 AM: 
###############################################################           88.3%
8:02:13 AM: 
################################################################
8:02:13 AM:  89.0%
8:02:13 AM: 
#############################################################
8:02:13 AM: ###          89.5%
8:02:13 AM: 
#################################################################
8:02:13 AM:  90.9%
8:02:13 AM: 
##################################################################
8:02:13 AM:  91.7%
8:02:13 AM: 
##################################################################        92.5%
8:02:14 AM: 
###################################################################
8:02:14 AM:  94.1%
8:02:14 AM: 
####################################################################
8:02:14 AM:  94.8%
8:02:14 AM: 
####################################################################
8:02:14 AM:  95.6%
8:02:14 AM: 
#####################################################################
8:02:14 AM:  96.1%
8:02:14 AM: 
#####################################################################     96.5%
8:02:14 AM: 
#####################################################################     97.1%
8:02:14 AM: 
###################################################
8:02:14 AM: ###################    97.6%
8:02:14 AM: 
######################################################################    98.2%
8:02:14 AM: 
#######################################################################   98.6%
8:02:15 AM: 
###################################################################
8:02:15 AM: ####   99.0%
8:02:15 AM: 
######################################################################
8:02:15 AM: #   99.8%
8:02:15 AM: 
########################################################################
8:02:15 AM: 100.0%
8:02:15 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
8:02:15 AM: Checksums matched!
8:02:17 AM: Now using node v11.5.0 (npm v6.4.1)
8:02:18 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
8:02:19 AM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
8:02:19 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
8:02:19 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
8:02:19 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
8:02:19 AM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
8:02:19 AM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
8:02:19 AM: Installing yarn at version 1.3.2
8:02:19 AM: Installing Yarn!
8:02:19 AM: > Downloading tarball...
8:02:19 AM: [1/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.3
8:02:19 AM: .2/yarn-v1.3.2.tar.gz --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.r76iL9IFsO
8:02:19 AM:   % Total    % Receiv
8:02:19 AM: ed % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
8:02:19 AM:                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Sp
8:02:19 AM: eed
8:02:19 AM: 
  0     0    0     0    0     0
8:02:19 AM:   0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
8:02:20 AM: 
100    91  100    91    0     0    312      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   313
8:02:21 AM: 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
8:02:21 AM: 
100   608    0   608    0     0    487      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  593k
8:02:21 AM: 
100  865k  100  865k    0     0   514k      0  0:00
8:02:21 AM: :01  0:00:01 --:--:--  514k
8:02:21 AM: [2/2]: https://
8:02:21 AM: yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.3.2/yarn-v1.3.2.tar.gz.asc --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.
8:02:21 AM: r76iL9IFsO.asc
8:02:21 AM: 
100    95  100    95    0     0   2206      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-
8:02:21 AM: -  2206
8:02:21 AM: 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--
8:02:21 AM: --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   612    0   612    0     0   3167      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  597k
8:02:21 AM: 
100  1027  100  1027    0     0   4452      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --
8:02:21 AM: :--:--  4452
8:02:21 AM: > Verifying integrity...
8:02:21 AM: gpg: Signature made Thu 02 Nov 2017 04:44:10 PM UTC using RSA key ID FD2497F5
8:02:21 AM: gpg: Good signature from "Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>"
8:02:21 AM: gpg: Note: This key has expired!
8:02:21 AM: Primary key fingerprint: 72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 C907  BBB7 1646 B01B
8:02:21 AM:  86E5 0310
8:02:21 AM:      Subkey fingerprint: 6A01 0C51 6600 6599 AA17  F081 46C2 130D FD24 97F5
8:02:21 AM: > GPG signature looks good
8:02:21 AM: > Extracting to ~/.yarn...
8:02:21 AM: > Adding to $PATH...
8:02:21 AM: > We've added the following to your /opt/buildhome/.profile
8:02:21 AM: > If this isn't the profile of your current shell then please add the following to your correct profile:
8:02:21 AM: export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
8:02:21 AM: 
8:02:22 AM: > Successfully installed Yarn 1.3.2! Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.
8:02:22 AM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.3.2
8:02:23 AM: yarn install v1.3.2
8:02:23 AM: (node:1370) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
8:02:23 AM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
8:02:24 AM: [2/4] Fetching packages...
8:02:42 AM: info fsevents@1.2.8: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
8:02:42 AM: info "fsevents@1.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
8:02:42 AM: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
8:02:42 AM: warning "gatsby > pnp-webpack-plugin > ts-pnp@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
8:02:42 AM: warning "gatsby > mini-css-extract-plugin > schema-utils > ajv-errors@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "ajv@>=5.0.0".
8:02:42 AM: warning " > gatsby-plugin-sass@2.0.11" has unmet peer dependency "node-sass@^4.9.0".
8:02:42 AM: warning "gatsby-plugin-sass > sass-loader@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
8:02:50 AM: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
8:02:55 AM: Done in 32.09s.
8:02:55 AM: NPM modules installed using Yarn
8:02:55 AM: (node:1495) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
8:02:56 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
8:02:56 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
8:02:56 AM: unset GOOS;
8:02:56 AM: unset GOARCH;
8:02:56 AM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
8:02:56 AM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
8:02:56 AM: go version >&2;
8:02:56 AM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
8:02:56 AM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
8:02:56 AM: Installing missing commands
8:02:56 AM: Verify run directory
8:02:56 AM: Executing user command: yarn build
8:02:56 AM: yarn run v1.3.2
8:02:56 AM: (node:1548) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
8:02:56 AM: $ gatsby build
8:02:59 AM: success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.034 s
8:03:00 AM: success load plugins — 0.785 s
8:03:00 AM: success onPreInit — 0.006 s
8:03:00 AM: success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.006 s
8:03:00 AM: success initialize cache — 0.009 s
8:03:00 AM: success copy gatsby files — 0.027 s
8:03:00 AM: success onPreBootstrap — 0.010 s
8:03:00 AM: success source and transform nodes — 0.172 s
8:03:00 AM: success building schema — 0.413 s
8:03:00 AM: success createPages — 0.041 s
8:03:00 AM: success createPagesStatefully — 0.036 s
8:03:00 AM: success onPreExtractQueries — 0.003 s
8:03:00 AM: success update schema — 0.035 s
8:03:01 AM: success extract queries from components — 0.203 s
8:03:01 AM: success run static queries — 0.015 s — 4/4 282.72 queries/second
8:03:07 AM: success run page queries — 6.163 s — 8/8 1.30 queries/second
8:03:07 AM: success write out page data — 0.004 s
8:03:07 AM: success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
8:03:36 AM: success Build manifest and related icons — 0.217 s
8:03:36 AM: success onPostBootstrap — 0.219 s
8:03:36 AM: info bootstrap finished - 39.680 s
8:04:06 AM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles — 30.272 s
8:04:10 AM: success Building static HTML for pages — 3.994 s — 8/8 12.70 pages/second
8:04:10 AM: info Done building in 74.085 sec
8:04:11 AM: Done in 74.58s.
8:04:11 AM: Function Dir: /opt/build/repo/.netlify/functions
8:04:11 AM: TempDir: /tmp/zisi-753014076
8:04:11 AM: Prepping functions with zip-it-and-ship-it 0.3.1
8:04:12 AM: [ { path: '/tmp/zisi-753014076/access-token.zip', runtime: 'js' },
8:04:12 AM:   { path: '/tmp/zisi-753014076/auth-redirect.zip', runtime: 'js' },
8:04:12 AM:   { path: '/tmp/zisi-753014076/auth.zip', runtime: 'js' },
8:04:12 AM:   { path: '/tmp/zisi-753014076/vault.zip', runtime: 'js' } ]
8:04:12 AM: Prepping functions complete
8:04:12 AM: Caching artifacts
8:04:12 AM: Started saving node modules
8:04:12 AM: Finished saving node modules
8:04:12 AM: Started saving yarn cache
8:04:12 AM: Finished saving yarn cache
8:04:12 AM: Started saving pip cache
8:04:12 AM: Finished saving pip cache
8:04:12 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
8:04:12 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
8:04:12 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
8:04:12 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
8:04:12 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
8:04:12 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
8:04:12 AM: Started saving go dependencies
8:04:12 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
8:04:15 AM: Build script success
8:04:15 AM: Starting to deploy site from 'public'
8:04:15 AM: Creating deploy tree 
8:04:15 AM: 15 new files to upload
8:04:15 AM: 0 new functions to upload
8:04:17 AM: Starting post processing
8:04:17 AM: Minifying bundle
8:04:19 AM: Minifying bundle
8:04:22 AM: Minifying bundle
8:04:24 AM: Minifying bundle
8:04:27 AM: Minifying bundle
8:04:29 AM: Minifying bundle
8:04:31 AM: Post processing done
8:04:32 AM: Site is live
8:04:46 AM: Finished processing build request in 2m53.782877402s
8:04:46 AM: Shutting down logging, 0 messages pending
```

**Update**:

I was following [this](https://www.robertcooper.me/front-end-javascript-environment-variables) post about `.env` variables in Gatsby project.

It suggests introducing another variable, e.g. `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV` and set it up manually. I was able to run `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=development netlify dev` as expected, though adding `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=development netlify dev` command under scripts in `package.json` and running `yarn develop` was causing an endless loop. After getting in the loop once you are not able to run  `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=development netlify dev` anymore without getting in the loop.

This question was also posted on [Netlify Forum](https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-change-node-env-for-netlify-functions/1366/6)

Comment: Have you tried to update netlify-cli?, with version 2.11.19 seems to work.

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of netlify

Comment: You don't get this error when deploying to Netlify?

Comment: @talves No errors on netlify. I have added netlify build log to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The functions path you are using is a proxy path in production (`/.netlify/functions/`). Locally using (`netlify dev`) the netlify development workflow will use that path to watch for compiled changes of your functions.

Move the functions directory to a different location (in example `/src/functions`) and change the `netlify.toml` build.functions = "functions". Netlify will use that directory to get your bundled scripts.

Use a bundle command to build your functions in your workflow. Netlify has a cli called `netlify-lambda` that you can use (`yarn add netlify-lambda -D`). Add the build command to your build workflow.

```sh
$ netlify-lambda build src/functions
```

#### Common reasons for the infinite loop of `netlify dev`

The following are not valid and will cause `netlify dev` to keep calling itself for functions

- Setting the source of your functions to the same directory as the build
- Including the `netlify dev` command in the package `scripts.development` command. (in example `"development": "npm run netlify dev")

***NOTE:*** When using functions on Netlify, you need to bundle your dependencies into your functions or they will not resolve when they are deployed.

Comment: even after updating `netlify.toml` with `build.functions = "functions"` and moving `functions` directory to the root of the project I get the same error.

Comment: Interesting, it worked for me. Are you building the functions into that location? Now that I think of it. I use `netlify-lambda` to build from `/src/functions` into the `/functions` directory.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason. I don't have `netlify-lambda` as a dependency in my project.

Comment: I doubt that is the reason. After looking at your code, I think the reason might be the require of a function to a function. Maybe just put the `auth-redirect.js` into a subfolder, since it is not going to be a function.

Comment: I have moved my auth-redirect.js https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-dev-blog-starter/tree/master/.netlify and edited netlify.toml command to inject CONTEXT=production https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-dev-blog-starter. I was able to run netlify dev without endless loop, though my production build fails with 500. Which most likely means that CONTEXT is not equal to production. Here is the link on production https://gatsby-dev-blog-starter.netlify.com/blog/github-comments/

Comment: I followed my recommendations in the answer for your code and removed the functions from `.netlify` to `src` and moved `auth-redirect`, and it worked for me.

Comment: can you please let me know if I missed anything from what you said, bс I still run in the endless loop. Here is the link on the diff https://github.com/iamskok/gatsby-dev-blog-starter/compare/netlify-lambda-issue?expand=1

Comment: My steps:

1. Move `/.netlify/functions/auth-redirect.js` => `src/auth-redirect.js`. 
2. Move `/.netlify/functions` => `src/functions`. 
3. `yarn add -D netlify lambda`. 
4. add `yarn build` script `netlify-lambda build src/functions` 
5. update `yarn develop` with `yarn build` - `npm run build:functions && CONTEXT=development 6etlify dev`
7. fix path to `auth-redirect.js` from `src/access-token.js`.
8. fix axios get request path from `src/access-token.js`.  
9. fix axios post request path from react component `src/components/commentForm.js`.